# How to store data into a view in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I store data into a numpy view without changing the `view` into a `copy`?  This code snippet examplifies my question:

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> #-- init arrays and view
>>> a = np.ones([4])
>>> z = np.zeros([2,4])
>>> z0 = z[0,:]  #-- view
>>> z0.flags.owndata
False

>>> #-- This works!
>>> #-- modify view in-place
>>> np.add(a,z0,z0)
>>> z0.flags.owndata
False
>>> z
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])


>>> #-- reinit arrays and view
>>> z = np.zeros([2,4])
>>> z0 = z[0,:]  #-- view

>>> #-- This does NOT work!
>>> #-- store data into view
>>> z0 = a 
>>> z0.flags.owndata
True
```

I know about in-place modifications using `+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` and numpy functions that take an `out` parameter, so you can do things like `np.abs(x, x)` to take the absolute value of `x` in-place.

But how to just store data into a `view` without modification?

Abusing the `add` function (to add zero and store) works but doesn't feel 'right':

```
np.add(a,0,z0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `z0 = a`, then `z0` is the same object as `a` by python logic. What you want to do is this:

```
z0[...] = a
```

using the slicing syntax. Which uses the in-place `__setitem__` python logic. On numpy 1.7. or later you could use `np.copyto` as well, which is probably a little faster, but I like the slicing syntax personally.